# How to assign binary value using CASE statement in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to assign binary values to strings in a column (1 for "Y" and 0 for "N"), but when I run the following query, it states "SELECT Failed. 5628:  Column Y not found..."

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
CASE 
  WHEN c.Audience="Y" THEN 1 
  WHEN c.Audience="N" THEN 0
  ELSE "NA"
END
FROM CUSTOMER_INFO a
LEFT JOIN CUST_MAIL b...
```

It seems to be assuming "Y" is referring to a column rather than the field value, which is what I would like.

Any ideas on how I can modify this query to accommodate my needs?

Thank you.

Comment: SQL uses single quotes to denote string literals. Try `WHEN c.Audience='Y' THEN 1 `

Comment: Yes, double quotes are reserved for field identifiers and labels.

Comment: Wow.  Where was my head?  I'm embarrassed for asking such a rookie question.  Thanks for the quick replies!